Decorator causes a problem AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute
I was working on my project about matrixes. I write method that multiply every element on number and function that sums matrices:
class SquareMatrix():
    def __init__(self, rows, random=False, *args):
        self.rows = rows

        def random_sequence(rows):
            "Creates a random sequence"
            sequence = []
            n = 1
            while n <= rows:
                a = randint(1, 100)
                sequence.append(a)
                n += 1
            return sequence

        def type_check(args):
            """Checks if arguments fit for methods"""

            if isinstance(args[0], int):
                return list(args)
            elif (isinstance(args[0], list) or isinstance(args[0], tuple)) and len(args) == 1:
                return args[0]
            else:
                print("Only lists or matrix's elements individually")

        if random == True:
            matrix = random_sequence(rows ** 2)
            self.matrix = matrix

        elif args != None:
            self.matrix = type_check(args)

        else:
            print("No arguments were entered")
            pass

    def showup(self):
        n = 1
        matrix = ""
        for a in self.matrix:
            if n % self.rows != 0:
                print(a, end=" ")
            elif n % self.rows == 0:
                print(a, end=" ")
                print("\n", end="")
            n += 1
        print("\n")
    @func_execution
    def multiply_on_number(self, number):
        n = 0
        for a in self.matrix:
            b = a * number
            self.matrix[n] = b
            n += 1
        return self

@func_execution
def matrix_sum(*matrixes):
    # Checking the matrix size compliance

    test = matrixes[0].rows
    for matrix in matrixes:
        if matrix.rows != test:
            print("Only matrices of the same size !")
            return False
    sum_matrixe = SquareMatrix(rows = test, random=True)
    sum_matrixe.multiply_on_number(number=0)
    n = 0

Then i created 3 instance of matrix class and sumed them up:
m1 = SquareMatrix(3, random=True)
m1.showup()
m1.multiply_on_number (2)
m1.showup()
print(type(m1))

sdf = [7, 45, 34, 356, 22, 11, 55, 33, 44]
m2 = SquareMatrix(3, False, sdf)
m2.showup()
print(type(m2))

m3 = SquareMatrix(3, False, 22, 11, 44, 22, 11, 44, 22, 11, 44)
m3.showup()
print(f"type(m3)")

b = matrix_sum(m1, m2, m3)
print(f"type(b)")

print(type (b))
b.showup()

but when i tried to call method showup() for variable b i get this error message:
'NoneType' object has no attribute 'showup'

Also i have debug decorator:
def func_execution (func):
    def descriptor (*args,**kwargs):
        print(f"\n\n\n\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tRunning {func.__name__}")
        print(f"Description: {func.__doc__}")
        print(f"\t\tUsing next pos arguments: {args}")

        n = 1
        print("Checking pos arguments type:")
        for arg in args:
            print(f"\t{n}. {type(arg)}")
            n +=1
        else:n = 1

        print(f"\tUsing next key arguments: {kwargs}")
        print("Checking key arguments type:")
        for kwarg in kwargs:
            print(f"\t{n}. {type(kwarg)}")
            n += 1
        print(f"\tresult of execution - {func(*args,**kwargs)}")
    return  descriptor

I think the problem is in the decorator, because when i delete it or delete reference at matrix_sum - everything works fine.
But still i don't understand how to make decorator and function work together.

Somewhere in the parts of your code that you are not showing us, you are trying to get the showup attribute from something, and that something is None. Figuring out what that something is, where it came from, and why it is None instead of whatever it was supposed to be, should give hints about the cause. See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8949252/why-do-i-get-attributeerror-nonetype-object-has-no-attribute-something . Hint: Are you perhaps using the return value of a decorated function somewhere?

Sorry, I just didn't want to overload the question with the body of the class, as it turned out to be larger than I originally expected. I've supplemented the question

@TurePålsson thank you for your reply. I think you're right that the problem is using the return value of a decorated function. However, I find it strange that the decorator doesn't work only with a function  matrix_sum,  but for example a method  multiply_on_number  simply returns a modified instance

You never use the return value from multiply_on_number, but you do use the return value from matrix_sum(). If you were to check the return value from multiply_on_number, you would find that that, too, is None.

I believe that if you were to write a [MCVE], you would realize what goes wrong.
